# Why didn't the Hulk fight Hela?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

We see the Hulk fight against many beings in *Thor: Ragnarok*. After fighting Fenris he had the opportunity to fight with Thor and team against Hela but didn't.  Why not?

Comment: 1. Hulk doesn't have any personal stakes in a fight with Hela. She's Thor's sister, and she murdered Valkyrie's entire "tribe", so it makes much more sense that they're the ones confronting her.
2. They've already established that "God of Thunder" mode Thor is more powerful than Hulk, and Thor, even when tapping into his power, can only inconvenience Hela. So it seems reasonable that Hulk wouldn't really bring much to the fight.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know you've got a point

Answer (score 8):

Because Hulk doesn’t get the chance, he falls in the water after Fenris and only gets up after Surtur has risen and Hela has been defeated.

Comment: I personally think that writers didn't want to put the hulk against her

Comment: @Ericallday Yeah, Hela would've sliced Hulk in half.